# Spring MVC controller mapping -- @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, spring-annotations

I'm trying to understand Spring MVC annotations.  I've looked at various tutorials, and I just want to make sure I understand.  In this example,

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
```

am I correct in understanding that welcome is the page making the request to the controller, and not the page the controller sends the response to?

Comment: If you send a `http://someurl/contextpath/welcome` request from your browser, it will be handled by the method where you have put the @RequestMapping annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your phrasing correctly, you are right. The `@RequestMapping` annotation specifies a URL for which the controller will be invoked to generate page content. `@RequestMapping("/welcome")` means that when a browser requests `http://yoursite.com/welcome` this controller will be invoked. The annotation does not specify the name of the view you use to render the page output, so you're free to make the controller construct its response using `home.jsp` or `index.jsp` or any other page you want; you do not need to have a view named "welcome." I'm not sure it really makes sense to say that the controller "sends the response to a page," though, because in HTTP the response to a request *is* a page; the basic idea of a controller is that given a request, it generates a web page to send back to the client as a response.